# The state (products) dont render in the v-data-table from vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

Im get the products state in my computed well , but when i add the products into the table i get ann error.
the products came from api call, What can I do to make the information appear?
the error is : [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="products"
      :search="search"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "products",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Year",
          align: "start",
          filterable: true,
          value: "year",
        },
        { text: "Item", value: "item" },
        { text: "Element", value: "element" },
        { text: "Value", value: "value" },
        { text: "Unit", value: "unit" },
        { text: "Area Code", value: "areacode" },
        { text: "Area", value: "area" },
      ],
  
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadProducts");
    
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.state.products
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: error seems fairly straight forward.  `products`, which you're assigning to the `v-data-table` items prop, is a single object, but the table expects an array.  have you debugged `products` to verify this?

Comment: you can see in my edited photo that i get the products into my component.

Comment: so it's confirmed that products is an object which v-data-table won't accept because `items` needs to be an array.  Do you mean to pass in `products.records` instead since it's an array?  try `:items="products.records"`

Comment: Now the error is gone, but I need to get to the fields object and to show in the table the value of him , see the updated image

Comment: that's controlled by the `headers` array.  point the value of each header object to the appropriate item field.  for example, area code object should be `{ text: "Area Code", value: "fields.area_code" },`